# Error after executing mysqli_query in some user defined function

Tags: php, mysqli

Content of **getUserName.php** file with one method getField:

```
<?php
function getfield($field)
{
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
    $query="SELECT `$field` FROM `user` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    if($query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
    {
      if($query_result=mysqli_fetch_field($query_run))
       {
        return $query_result;
       }
     } else {
        printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        }       
}  
?>
```

Content of **index.php** that includes **connection.php** that holds **$conn** object & **getUserName.php**:

```
<?php 
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('function.php');
$fname=getfield('Fname');
$lname=getfield('Lname');

echo $name=$fname.' '.$lname;
?>
```

After executing it, I got an error message like:

**`Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/confessi/public_html/college/profile/function.php on line 8`**

Any idea? Why am I getting the error? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure `$conn` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `$conn` is not available in your `getfield` function's scope.

Declaring it global inside the function should do the trick:

```
<?php
function getfield($field)
{
    global $conn;

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        $query="SELECT `$field` FROM `user` WHERE `id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
        if($query_run=mysqli_query($conn,$query))
        {
            if($query_result=mysqli_fetch_field($query_run))
            {
                return $query_result;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
        }       
    }  
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$conn` is not defined in the local scope of `getfield($field)`. You need to send it as a paramater:

```
$fname=getfield($conn, 'Fname');
$lname=getfield($conn, 'Lname');

function getfield($conn, $field) {
    ...
```

Comment: Noep! not working... i received another error like: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /home/confessi/public_html/college/profile/function.php on line 7" 
line 7= $query line in function.php

Comment: @style Yes sorry. I edited.